# How to output/serialize correct YearMonth value to display on form using Spring annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, jsonserializer, datetimeformatter

I have the following variable in my POJO class being used to load the correct saved data into a form:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=YearMonthDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using=YearMonthDeserializer.class)
private YearMonth date;
```

The correct saved value that should be loaded into form is "12/2010". However, it gets displayed as "02/0101". I believe it is because the default YearMonth format is "2010-12" and its not recognizing how to output it in the form field with the given input mask. I have tried adding the @JsonFormat(pattern="MM/yyyy") annotation as well as the @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/yyyy") but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@JsonSerialize(using = YearMonthSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = YearMonthDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/yyyy")
YearMonth date;
```

output {"date":"04/2022"}